# Is modulo 10^9+7 useful in real world problems?

Tags: c++, exponent

Take for example 5^100000

In competitive programming a constraint is given as we should compute under 10^9+7 I understand why they are using it (to prevent an overflow)
But my question is **if the number resulting from a multiplication goes over 10^9+7 then it wraps around so the answer is not the exact value we are looking for.
Is this value obtained after modulo still useful in it's current form in real world problems or is it transformed somehow?**

example code

```
#define N 1000000007 // prime modulo value

    long int exponentiation(long int base,
                        long int exp)
{
    if (exp == 0)
        return 1;
  
    if (exp == 1)
        return base % N;
  
    long int t = exponentiation(base, exp / 2);
    t = (t * t) % N;
  
    // if exponent is even value
    if (exp % 2 == 0)
        return t;
  
    // if exponent is odd value
    else
        return ((base % N) * t) % N;
}

    int main()
{
    long int base = 5;
    long int exp = 100000;
  
    long int modulo = exponentiation(base, exp);
    cout << modulo << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
754573817
```

Comment: Oh, the shocking realization. :P Probably most competitive programming exercises you're doing have no real-world use.

Comment: voting to close "opinion based". It's not like you could get a right answer to this question. Only bashing competitive programming and anecdotic example of modulo usage in other fields like rendering and cryptography.

Comment: If modular exponentiation doesn't give "the value you're looking for", then it's not appropriate. Otherwise it is.

Comment: Modular arithmetic has many legitimate uses in the real world. Whether the modulo operation applied to the answer of any particular problem makes sense depends on the problem. Most competitive programming problems make no sense in the real world by themselves, even before the modulo.

Comment: @Jeffrey An anecdotal example seems to be exactly what OP is asking for. Or may be just "yes".

Comment: @eerorika exactly I was just curious if the value after doing modulus is useful like suppose the number is too big for any data type you can use for some reason but operating on the modulo of the value would perhaps still give the answer you are looking for

Comment: PKI modulus - research public key cryptography

Answer (score 0):

In asymmetric cryptographic systems or more broadly [Multiplicative groups of integers modulo n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) you often use the results of partially random modulo numbers.

In your specific example we are lucky 1000000007(`p`) is a prime number so `x` and `y` can be any number and the following holds true<sup>1</sup>:

```
(x * y) mod p == (x mod p) * (y mod p)
```

Lets construct a problem for example:
"Bacteria multiplies with the daily rate piped (1 < x < 2^32-1) into the application, the bacterian culture organizes into 1000000007-sized groups. After the last day return the size of the last group."

Having this knowlegde we can now instead of computing some ridiculously large number and then taking the modulo, we can:

```
foreach(x in input)
    output = output * (input mod 1000000007)
    output = output mod 1000000007
```

Limiting the required variable size to (rounded up to usual sizes) 64 bit instead of some unbounded width.

<sup>1</sup> <sup>Beeing a prime is actually a special form of the requirement `for any x used in the computation: gcd(x, p) == 1 must hold`</sup>